# Method to build patches using MSI

Tags: windows-installer, patch, msi-patch

I work in an application built upon Visual Studio 2010 and often make little fixes.

I need a method to send these fixes like a patch, a MSP file I guess, not the complete [MSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file. How can I do this?? Is there an article or a link?

Answer (score 2):

Patch is a difference between two MSIs. So to create a patch, you would need the original MSI package and the updated one.

Read the following articles in the MSDN:

- [Patching and Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579.aspx)
- [Patching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370578.aspx)
- [Creating a Patch Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368060.aspx)

I also have a step-by-step [instruction on how to create patches](http://alexyv.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/wix-patching/) using [WiX Toolset](http://wix.codeplex.com/).